# String splitting based on delimiter in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have string like this in oracle table

```
VM4 SPLA - WI NS V R STD #P59- 9 9 99 QTY 2 : S P LA - W IN SV RENT #P39-9999 QTY 3 : SPL A - WIN S VR SMB # P 3 9- 999 99 QTY 5    1
```

I need to split this string and insert into table using loop

```
name description           partnumber   Qty  objectstate
-------------------------------------------------------
VM4  SPLA - WI NS V R STD  P59- 9 9 99   2    1
VM4  S P LA - W IN SV RENT P39-9999      3    1
VM4  SPL A - WIN S VR SMB  P 3 9- 999 99 5    1
```

Help me how to do this using loop.

Comment: It is not obvious here what the delimiters on which to split the string are.  Do you know for a fact that `description`, `partnumber` and `Qty` will take certain formats?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
  string varchar2(4000);
  v_objstate number;
  v_name varchar2(100);
  v_description varchar2(100);
  v_partnumber varchar2(100);
  v_qty number;
  v_all_rows varchar2(4000);
  v_row varchar2(4000);
begin
  string := 'VM4 SPLA - WI NS V R STD #P59- 9 9 99 QTY 2 : S P LA - W IN SV RENT #P39-9999 QTY 3 : SPL A - WIN S VR SMB # P 3 9- 999 99 QTY 5    1';
  v_objstate := to_number(regexp_substr(string, '\d+$'));
  v_all_rows := regexp_replace(string, '\d+$');
  v_name := regexp_substr(v_all_rows, '\S+');
  v_all_rows := regexp_replace(v_all_rows, '^\s*\S+');
  for rec in (
    select regexp_substr(v_all_rows, '[^:]+', 1, level) as next_row 
    from dual connect by null is null
  ) loop
    v_row := trim(rec.next_row);
    exit when v_row is null;
    v_qty := to_number(trim(regexp_substr(v_row, '\d+\s*$')));
    v_row := regexp_replace(v_row, 'QTY\s*\d+\s*$');
    v_partnumber := trim(regexp_replace(v_row, '^.*#'));
    v_description := trim(regexp_replace(v_row, '#.*?$'));
    insert into your_table (name, description, partnumber, Qty, objectstate) 
      values (v_name, v_description, v_partnumber, v_qty, v_objstate);
  end loop;
end;
```